# Passing SelectList through ViewData to editor templates - not displayed properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, drop-down-menu

It's a bit complicated so bear with me.

Let's say I've got an example of a controller edit action defined like:

```
Node nd = _repo.getNode(id);

List<Category> ac = new List<Category>();
ac.AddRange(_repo.getCategories());
SelectList acl = new SelectList(ac, "category_id", "category_name", ac.Where(cat => cat.category_id == nd.category_id).First());

ViewData["category_id"] = acl;

return View(nd);
```

The view is templated like so:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Myapp.Models.Node>" %>
<% if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1) 
   { %>
<%= ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText %>
<% }
   else
   { %>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <% foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => pm.ShowForEdit && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm)))
       { %>
    <% if (prop.HideSurroundingHtml)
       { %>
    <%= Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName) %>
    <% }
       else
       { %>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-label" style="text-align: right;">
                <%= prop.IsRequired ? "*" : ""%>
                <%= Html.Label(prop.PropertyName)%>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <% if (ViewData.Keys.Contains(prop.PropertyName))
                   {
                       if ((ViewData[prop.PropertyName]).GetType().Name == "SelectList")
                            { %>
                                <%= Html.DropDownList(prop.PropertyName, (SelectList)ViewData[prop.PropertyName])%>
                            <% }
                                else
                                    { %>
                                        <%= Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)%>
                                    <% } %>                       
                  <% }
                   else
                   { %>
                <%= Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)%>
                <% } %>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessage(prop.PropertyName, "*")%>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <% } %>
    <% } %>
</table>
<% } %>
```

So, what the template does is display a dropdown list for every property for which  `ViewData["property_name"]` exists.

I've also defined `DisplayName` metadata attributes for every property of my Node class.

Now, the dropdown lists display fine and are being populated correctly, but:

1. The first value from a list is always selected, even though the SelectList selected value predicate is fine and does set a proper value (in the debugger at least).
2. Html.Label in the template returns a proper DisplayName for properties, but when I define a ViewData for them so as to display the dropdown list, the label resets to normal property name (ie. `category_id` instead of `Category`).

What gives? Can you think of any "neater" way to accomplish this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, no one's answering so there's my answer, maybe it comes in handy for someone:

**Do not** use your property names for ViewData keys! It messes up with the view model, so your views get confused and start to behave strangely.

Actually, best avoid the magic strings mess entirely, but if you insist, just use something like
 `ex.: ViewData[prop.PropertyName+"_list"]`. Your views are going to be fine now.